# How to use SpriteKit archives with SKSpriteNode subclasses

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

How can I use a spritekit archive file, where a SpriteNode is located, and have that SpriteNode instantiated "into" a subclass (using Swift?)

I can find the node using scene.childNodeWithName("mysprite") but I don't know how to make it into an instance of my subclass of SKSpriteNode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to set a custom class for a node in the SpriteKit editor in Xcode 6. (That'd be a great [feature request](http://bugreport.apple.com) to file with Apple, though.)

However, the `sks` files you produce in Xcode are just `NSKeyedArchiver` archives, and you can use `NSKeyedUnarchiver` options to control how your objects get instantiated at load time. So there's a (limited) option for changing classes at load time — you can see this in the template code when you create a new SpriteKit Game project in Xcode 6.

See the `SKNode` extension (or category in the ObjC version) in `GameViewController.m`: it uses the `NSKeyedUnarchiver` method [`setClass(_:, forClassName:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedUnarchiver_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSKeyedUnarchiver/setClass%3aforClassName%3a) to treat the `SKScene` instance in the archive as an instance of the template project's `GameScene` class instead. You can extend this pattern to create other custom scene classes from Xcode-created archives.

You'll notice, though, that `setClass(_:forClassName:)` works on a class-name basis, so it's of limited use if your archive contains several objects of the same class and you want to decode *one* of them as a different class than the rest. In that case, you might look into using other unarchiver tricks — for example, replacing an object in the [`unarchiver(_:didDecodeObject:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSKeyedUnarchiverDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSKeyedUnarchiverDelegate/unarchiver%3adidDecodeObject%3a) delegate method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this delegate https://github.com/ice3-software/node-archive-delegate
or, for swift implementation, smt like this:

```
class func unarchiveNodeFromFile(file:String)-> SKNode? {
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks") {
        var fileData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfFile(path, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
        var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: fileData)
        archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKNode")
        let node = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as SKNode
        archiver.finishDecoding()
        return node
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```